# Extending Models In Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model like this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
```

and an extended model:

```
 class Model2(Model1):
    .
    .
    .
```

With this query:

```
model1 = Model1.objects.all()
```

How can I find items that belongs to inherited model (Model2) with above query?

Edit:
I want to access this query from Model1:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
      def is_model2(self):
         m2 = self.objects.filter(model2__isnull=False)
             if m2.count() > 0:
                if self in m2:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the above query retrieve items belonging to both `Model1` and `Model2`?

Comment: Yes, it will, since all `Model2` are `Model1` due to inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `InheritanceManager` from [django-model-utils](https://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils). It'll return the correct instances, even when querying the base model.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Model1` doesn't have `class Meta: abstract = True`, this is [multi-table inheritance.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

You could use:

```
model2 = Model2.objects.all()
```

since all `Model2` objects are `Model1`, or you could go through your query one at a time:

```
for m in model1:
    try:
        m.model2 # Try to use the Model2 object
    except Model2.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

Or filter the query:

```
q = model1.filter(id__in=Model2.objects.all())
```

It's hard to tell which option is best from what little you give us.

**EDIT:** If you just want a function to tell you if a `Model1` is a `Model2`, then you just need:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    def is_model2(self):
        try:
            self.model2
        except Model2.DoesNotExist:
            return False
        return True
```

Comment: Or you can do it fast in one line (like in my answer). :-)

Comment: You really should explain what you answer does, how it works, etc.

Comment: `values_list()` is unnecessary, `id__in=Model2.objects.all()` is enough.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone, thanks, but : Manager isn't accessible via Model1 instances

Comment: What part is giving you that?

Comment: `class Model1(models.Model):
    def is_model2(self):
        try:
            self.model2
        except Model2.DoesNotExist:
            return False
        return True`

Comment: What version of Django are you using, and which line exactly is giving you the "Manager isn't accessible via Model1 instances" error?